# where to config LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL laravel 5.6.7

Tags: laravel-5.6

How to use slack logging functionality in laravel 5.6.7? I wrote a line LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL = "my slack url" in .env file and used Log::emergency("alert testing..."); but did not get any notification on slack. Also i have no idea where to configure slack channel it is required or not.

Comment: Are you sure your your `my slack url` is obtained from Webhook URL in the slack configuration, after you set up Incoming Webhooks? You can also try if the channel is working using curl or such. https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel 8.X**
Setting Slack log just in **4 Steps**:

1. Create Channel > Click on **Channel Name** > click on **Integration** tab > Click on **Add an App**
2. Now search app i.e. incoming webhook > Click on **Install** > Click on **Add to Slack** > Scroll down to **Select the channel** in which you wish to integrate.
3. Copy **Webhook URL** > Open .env file & mention below env name with webhook url.

   LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=COPIED-WEBHOOK-URL
4. Lastly, Open config/logging.php > Add **slack** in channels.stack.channels array as below image.
   [image: Code changes in logging.php file]

Done!!

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be too late but anyways somebody might find this helpful.

1. You have to **add incoming-webhook app** into your slack channel.

   [image]
2. It will generate **special URL** *(something like 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/...)* for you
3. Set it in your .evn file or as second argument of env() call in logging.php (as I done it)
   [image]
4. Check **slack.level** value because it is set pretty high and I wanted to get every mesage so I set it to **debug** (the lowest level possible) (visible in screenshot too)
5. You can now test if or example with **php artisan tinker** -> Log::error('Test works');

Hope this will help somebody